# C# Automapper Nested Object

Tags: c#, automapper

Ive searched for this for few days now and cant seem to get anything to work, I am using c# MVC Entity Framework with Automapper and im trying to achieve the below ViewModels (mainly LostDocumentVM) to be mapped from my database, all other properties will be set in controllers.

Here is my ViewModels...

```
DocumentVM
{
    Public Enum.HistoricType HistoricType {get;set;}
    Public DocumentChildVM Document { get; set;}
}

DocumentChildVM
{
    Public bool ShowHistoricLink {get;set;}
    Public IEnumerable<ListDocumentVM> DocumentsToReview {get;set;}
}

ListDocumentVM
{
    Public int Id {get;set;}
    Public string Name {get; set;}
    Public DateTime? ReviewDate {get;set;}
}
```

I initialise the DocumentVM like this...

```
DocumentVM documentVM = DataContext.SystemUser.Where(x=>x.SustemUserID==LoggedOnUserID).Project().To<DocumentVM>().SingleOrDefault();
```

And my mapping is like this...

```
Mapper.CreateMap<SystemUser,DocumentVM>()
.ForMember(dest=>dest.Document.DocumentsToReview, opt=>opt.MapFrom(src=>src.Documents.Where(x=>x.DocumentType == Enum.DocumentType.Assessment));
```

Im new to AutoMapper and struggling to get more advanced mappings to work.

Comment: In what way is this not working? Do you get an exception?

Comment: Forgot to mention that, the error i get it... Expression must resolve to top-level member and not any child object’s properties. Use a custom resolver on the child type or the AfterMap option instead. Its referring to dest.Document.DocumentsToReview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your ForMember member must refer to a member on the destination type, and yours is referring to a member on the child type. Instead, you'll need to create an AfterMap function that fills in this information on that child entity.

It's not difficult, but you have a bit of a strange set up where a child object Document has a property DocumentsToReview from another property on the parent DocumentVM:

```
documentVM.Document.DocumentsToReview = 
    src.Documents.Where(doc => doc.DocumentType == Enum.DocumentType.Assessment);
```

When you have to shuffle data between sibling/nephew members, it gets a little more challenging.

To do this with AfterMap:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<SystemUser, DocumentVM>()
    .AfterMap((src, dest) => dest.Document.DocumentsToReview = 
    src.Documents.Where(doc => doc.DocumentType == Enum.DocumentType.Assessment));
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, could you possibly give me a small code example of how to use the AfterMap on my CreateMap? Also I am abit confused about your second paragraph, I dont know what you mean by 'Document has a property DocumentsToReview from another property on the parent DocumentVM'. DocumentsToReview links to another child level called ListDocumentVM not DocumentVM.

The reason I have it designed like that is because in my main view I check which HistoricType is it and render a certain partial view, then that partial view checks to see if it should show a html link based on ShowHisoricLink

Comment: Then finally its passed into another partial view where the document data is finally rendered. There might be a better way to lay it out but thats how I've done it, i could of used ViewBag/ViewData but i much prefer strongly typed and the use of intellisense to make sure im selecting the correct element e.g. Model.ShowHistoricLink instead of ViewData["ShowHistoricLink"]